# Cleanest way to change database schema in EF6

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6

Currently we are writing a page in mvc5, with an oracle sql database connected with entitiy framework 6.

We currently have two schemas in the oracle database, one for testing and the other for development. The model in entitiy framework is generated from the development database, and works perfectly with it.

The problem comes, when changing the connection string to the testing schema. When the connection string is changed the application is unable to locate the tables (as they still reference the development schemes).

Currently I can fix this, by deleting all the tables from the model, and recreating the model from the correct schema, or manually editing every file referencing the schema. Both solutions are kinda tiresome and error prone.

How is this scenario usually dealt with?

**EDIT**

It seems that changing the database and retaining the schema, does not produce any error. So this is only schema related.

Comment: Is it an option for you to change to code-first? In code-first you can specify the schema in the mapping.

Comment: @GertArnold I could try that. So I could just read the schema from the connection string, and set it programatically in the mapping?

Comment: No, the schema isn't set by the connection string, but you can add any entry in the config file yourself by which you can set the schema.

Comment: @GertArnold The problem with code first is that in order to create the tables, it needs to create the database. The database has to remain the same, as some schemas are used for other systems.

Comment: You can use code-first without migrations. It only means that when you change the database, you also change the model. That's not as bad as it sounds, *maybe* even better than updating an edmx, because you're 100% in control. Moreover, edmx support is going to disappear in EF7.

Comment: @GertArnold I think the code first approach should be the answer. I tried to use create code first from the database, but i am getting metadata exception, as something is wrong with the connection string. Could you post the answer switching to code first and the migration process from edmx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With fluent mappings in Entity Framework code-first you can indicate the default schema at runtime. This is one statement in `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext` subclass, for instance:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dev");
```

You're used to regenerating the model from the database, from which I conclude that the model doesn't contain many (or any) customizations that would make model generation a painstaking operation. This also should make it relatively easy to move to code-first. So I'd recommend you do that.

In Visual Studio, you can generate a code-first model from an existing database by adding an "ADO.Net Entity Data Model" from the templates that come with Entity Framework tools for Visual Studio. (Probably pre-installed). Choose the option "Code First from database" and follow the guidelines.

If you do that, you'll find a connection string in the project containing the model. This connection string may serve as template for the connection string you will put in the config file of your executing assembly. You'll notice that it *doesn't* look like...

> `metadata=res://* ... provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;...&quot;"`

This is the connection string that belongs to a database-first edmx model. It contains a path to the metadata files that are generated as resources into the assembly. Instead, the connection string will be a simple ADO.Net connection string. With code-first, EF will generate the meta data at runtime.

If you have this, you can add an entry in your config file for the default database schema and use that to set the schema as I showed above.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is a perfect use case for using [entity framework command interceptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#BuildingBlocks). I just tried and it works perfectly, even for Entity Framework DB-First approach.

You can register a custom command interceptor like this:

```
DbInterception.Add(new ReplaceSchemaInterceptor(newSchema: "[my]"));
```

This line will replace `[dbo]` schema name with the `[my]` schema name, before the query reaches the database. Luckily, schema name is enclosed with square brackets when Entity Framework generates the command text, so it's easy to match and replace. BTW, I'm not an Oracle expert, so I'm assuming that Oracle queries also include schemas in the same format. If not, then maybe you will have to tweak the implementation a bit (to replace the schema from whatever format it is generated by EF).

ReplaceSchemaInterceptor is a class that implements IDbCommandInterceptor interface. Inside this class, you need to replace the schema with your own schema.  Below is the implementation of this class:

```
class ReplaceSchemaInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor 
{
    private readonly string _newSchema;

    public ReplaceSchemaInterceptor(string newSchema)
    {
        _newSchema = newSchema;
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("[dbo]", _newSchema);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("[dbo]", _newSchema);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("[dbo]", _newSchema);
    }
}
```

And lastly, the code is not perfect. You need to add some null checks for the constructor parameters, and maybe get rid of the code duplication inside implementation methods when replacing command text (extract into reusable method?). Right now it just does what you had asked for.

Comment: Your solution might solve an issue I have. Read it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/573). Do you know if this interception would cause performance issues?

Comment: This should not have a noticeable performance difference as compared to the built in implementation. It only depends on how fast your code replaces schema name with another schema name. That's all it adds. Only performance hit can be in how well your interceptor is written.

Comment: I am leaning towards using the interceptor, because I don't want to manually change the DefaultSchema entry that every migration creates in the ".resx" file. I havent found any other solution yet, except yours which gives me absolute control. Do you think if this is overkill for my case? One more thing, the DbContext is from a 3rd party so I dont have the choice of using `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");`

Comment: My solution is perfect when you want to switch between schemas during runtime. But in your case, do you have any other option?

Comment: I dont know yet. Seems like my situation is forcing me to "switch-back" to the correct schema dynamically, because EF6 is tricking my code to use "dbo" schema on its own at run time. Hence your solution would work for me. I usually set a custom schema name in the first migration itself. That way I don't have to add a useless schema renaming migration just because EF6 WILL default to its beloved "dbo" and I don't like "dbo" :-). Sigh!

Comment: I see. If this seems to be the only option, there is no need to worry about it being an overkill. In general, as I said, I would recommend this approach if you want to switch between schemas (i.e. support multiple schemas). Otherwise, when there is no other choice, you have to use this solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something we are doing here at my workplace.

### Use synonyms for your objects!

A possibility would be to create synonyms dynamically for your test tables - and remove references to schema in your files

Say the user that connects is `CONNECT_USER` - must be different user as the schemas you're using which are `SCHEM_DEV` and `SCHEM_TEST`.

Here is how I would do the switch (Oracle PL/SQL scripting - connected as `CONNECT_USER`):

```
begin
  for x in (select * from all_tables where owner='SCHEM_DEV')   
  loop
    --- drop synonyms on SCHEM_DEV objects
    execute immediate 'drop synonym '||table_name ;
    --- create synonyms on SCHEM_TEST objects
    execute immediate ' create or replace synonym '||table_name||' for SCHEM_TEST.'||table_name ;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Something like this should be forbidden to do. Wrong on so many levels.